# Understanding This Use Case for a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working through a python tutorial and came across this use of a dictionary. Unfortunately there was ZERO explanation as to what exactly is going on, and I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what is happening.

To parse the data below:

```
[TERRA]
dir  = /data/geospatial_19/ucfajlg/fire/Angola/MOD09
name = MODIS TERRA data
year = 2004
doy_start = 214
doy_end = 245
file_list = files/data/modis_files2a.txt

[AQUA]
dir  = /data/geospatial_19/ucfajlg/fire/Angola/MYD09
name = MODIS AQUA data
year = 2004
doy_start = 214
doy_end = 245
file_list = files/data/modis_files2b.txt
```

we are using this code:

```
fp = open(r'c:\files_folder\modis.txt', 'r')

modis = {}
this_section = modis

for line in fp.readlines():
    line = line.strip()

    if len(line) and line[0] == '[' and line [-1] == ']':
        section = line[1:-1]
        modis[section] = this_section = {}

    elif len(line) and line.find("=") != -1:
        key,value = line.split("=")
        this_section[key.strip()] = value.strip()   

print modis
```

It produces the nested dictionary below, but I don't understand how.

```
{'AQUA': {'doy_end': '245', 'doy_start': '214', 'name': 'MODIS AQUA data', 'year': '2004', 'file_list': 'files/data/modis_files2b.txt', 'dir': '/data/geospatial_19/ucfajlg/fire/Angola/MYD09'}, 'TERRA': {'doy_end': '245', 'doy_start': '214', 'name': 'MODIS TERRA data', 'year': '2004', 'file_list': 'files/data/modis_files2a.txt', 'dir': '/data/geospatial_19/ucfajlg/fire/Angola/MOD09'}}
```

What is happening here: `modis[section] = this_section = {}`?

Does this maneuver have a name?

Comment: It is equivalent to `this_section = {}`, `modis[section] = this_section`.

Comment: Always nice to see a MODIS user

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem apologies, i don't think i was super clear: the reason this line confuses me is that before we get to it we make `this_section = modis`. i don't understand why we would then insert `this_section` (which is the `modis` dict) into the `modis` dict. there is some logic here i'm not understanding. is there not another way to add a dictionary to a dictionary than by inserting one into itself?

Comment: I added more to my answer to explain the purpose of the `this_section = modis` line and why the `modis` dictionary is never inserted into itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment pointed out, the line `modis[section] = this_section = {}` is a short way of saying the equivalent two lines:

```
this_section = {}
modis[section] = this_section
```

But that could use more unpacking.

The previous line is

```
section = line[1:-1]
```

which is reached when the variable `line` is a string that begins and ends with square brackets. In other words, `line` holds the name of a section in your data file. Then `section = line[1:-1]` copies everything except the surrounding brackets, so the variable `section` now holds the name of the section. (The first time it is executed results in the value `'TERRA`', for example.) That variable is badly named--it should be named `section_name` since it is not actually the section, but I'll continue to use the given name.

Then `this_section = {}` makes a new, empty section, in the form of an empty dictionary. Immediately afterwards, `modis[section] = this_section` puts that new empty dictionary inside the larger `modis` dictionary and associates the section with the section name. That's how `'TERRA': {...}` ends up inside the result dictionary.

The next few lines that start `elif len(line) and line.find("=") != -1:` then fill out the inner dictionary, still named `this_section`. Each of the lines in the section in the file get put into that inner dictionary, one line at a time, after parsing the key name and key value out of the file line.

So this is the overall flow of the program. The data file is opened and the result dictionary `modis` is created as an empty dictionary. The first section name in the data file is found so an inner, empty dictionary is created with the proper section name. Each line in that section in the data file is then put into the inner dictionary in the desired format. When a new section name is found, a new inner empty dictionary is created for that new section. And so on.

Is that clear?

---

Your latest comment asks about the two lines just after the `fp = open(` line. The statement `modis = {}` is clear: it creates the overall dictionary to be empty, to be filled in later.

The next line `this_section = modis` is subtle. Basically, it is meant for error-checking. The basic flow of the program assumes that the data file is a sequence of sections, with each section starting with the section name in square brackets. But what if the first section has no section name? The program sets the first inner-dictionary to the *outer* dictionary, so any item lines will be put directly into the outer dictionary. This way, the item lines have somewhere to go, even though no inner-dictionary exists for them. If the first section does have a section name, then this initial line ends up doing nothing since the variable `this_section` will immediately become a new empty inner dictionary. There is no situation where the `modis` dictionary would be inserted into itself.

Another way to handle that would have been to create an initial inner-dictionary, with a null name such as the empty string, or the `None` value, to hold any rogue nameless initial section. Then at the end, the program could check if that section was used, and if not just delete it. But that would use more lines of code and look more complicated--the solution used adds only one code line and is simple in appearance, even if it is not simple in meaning.